# youtube statistics API broken

Tags: api, video, youtube, usage-statistics

First of all, sorry for my badly articulated question, this is my first ever question to post here.

I have programmed a youtube search engine for myself and used it for a long time. Yesterday i noticed it was not working correctly anymore.
I spent some time looking for the problem and soon enough noticed that some of the video statistic data queries return nothing.

Here is an example API URL that doesn't work:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=nNmfb2FQ8MA&key=PUT API KEY HERE&fields=items(statistics)&part=statistics

If you replace the video ID it should return the statistics of the video.
It just doesnt show anything for some youtube IDs for some reason